# Active Directory Site not showing up in dns

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have active Directory installed on three domain controllers spread over three sites, linked by permanent VPN connections. However I have noticed that in the dns snapin only two of these sites are listed in the sites container for my domain. I haven't encountered any problems and everything looks correct in Active Directory Sites and Services.

Does anyone know if this is going to cause problems for this site and if so what is the safest way to correct it.

To clarify - I have 3 active directory domain controllers which are each a site, all are dns servers, no errors in the event logs on all 3 servers. This setup has been running for several months with no noticable problems. DNS is the same on all three sites in the snap-in.

Comment: Results of dcdiag:

Testing server: SITE1\SERVER1
Starting test: Connectivity
The host 12328886-ebbd-425d-8cfc-5da0c70e1017._msdcs.domain.local
could not be resolved to an IP address.  Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc
Although the Guid DNS name (12328886-ebbd-425d-8cfc-5da0c70e1017._msdcs.domain.local couldn't be resolved, the server name (server1.domain.local) resolved to the IP address (192.168.0.1) and was pingable.  Check the IP address is registered correctly with the DNS server.

all tests passed fine on other DCs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running netdiag first on every site, i suspect it's a connectivity problem. 90% of active directory problem is related to DNS.

netdiag /v and netdiag /fix

also check wether the server is pointing to the correct DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

try running dcdiag on your domain controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't all that clear. When you say "three sites", do you mean three AD sites? Are all three DCs also DNS servers? Have you run dcdiag to check for obvious faults? Are there any errors in the event log?

Comment: I can't find dsadiag is it a microsoft diagnostic tool or do I need to download it from somewhere>

Comment: sorry: I typed "dsadiag" when I meant "dcdiag"

Answer (score 1):

do all DC's (DNS Servers) have the same Service Pack installed? All DNS servers need to have the same version number to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given AD enough time to replicate the DNS data to all domain controllers? Assuming you are using AD-integrated DNS. In the DNS snap-in try connecting to the other sites and see if the DNS is different.